# How to use model in mvc DB First pattern?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-database-first

this class comes from db

```
public class Company
{
    public new Guid ID { get; set; }
    public new String Name { get; set; }
}
```

I want to use class CompanyModel as model in mvc 
but it doesn't works

```
public class CompanyModel : Company
{
    public new Guid ID { get { return base.ID; } set { base.ID = ID; } }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Company Name")]
    public new String Name { get { return base.Name; } set { base.Name = Name; } }
}
```

Is there ways to do something like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend you using a view model instead:

```
public class CompanyViewModel
{
    public new Guid ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Company Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }    
}
```

Then in your controller action you could map between your domain EF model and the view model that will get passed to the view. To simplify this mapping you could use a tool like [`AutoMapper`](http://automapper.org/).